# How can I fix Wacom Intuos5 button mapping and compatibility issues?

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet, remapping

For the most part my tablet works out of box but with limitations.

The wheel when scrolling just flickers the 4 leds.

I cannot map modifier buttons <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

I want to be able to activate precision mode like I did on Windows.

It would also be great to have the overlay when I hover my finger over the buttons.

Also, since I got the wireless accessory for my tablet not that long ago I have come across a new problem: I lost some of my mapping options.

I used to have the 6 buttons, ring button switcher, and 4 ring up/down modes. Now all I have is 3 ring up/down modes.